# Pyramid number pattern doesn't print the correct output

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

This is the output I want to print for the input number 5:

```
1

11

202

3003

40004
```

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            if(i==1 && j==1){cout<<'1';}

            else if(i!=1 && i<=n && j<=i && j!=1){  cout<<i-1;
               for(int k=0;k<i-2;k++){cout<<'0';}
               cout<<i-1;

            }
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This prints the correct pattern but it prints the pattern in ith line i times, for example instead of 202, 202202 gets printed and so on for the other rows. I am stuck where the logic in my loop is incorrect, so need help with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Try this code**

```
#include <iostream>
```

`using namespace std;`

```
int main(){
int row;
cin >> row;

if(row>=1)
{
    for(int i =0; i<row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<=i;j++)
        {
            if(i==0)
                cout<<'1';
            else if(j==0 || j==i)
                cout<<i;
            else
                cout<<'0';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}}
```

Here, whatever value you give greater than 0 should be displayed first as 1 and if you entered 0, nothing should be displayed. So all you have to do is check if the value you entered is greater than 0 and the display 1 0n the first iteration.
Suppose you gave the input a value of 2 or greater tan 2. This is what should be shown after the loop is run until the second iteration

1

11

Here, in the first iteration, if i = 0 is used to display the first line, then check i == 0 in the inner loop and then '1' should be displayed.

In the second iteration, j=0 again in the inner loop. Then the first thing to look at is whether j==0. Because 0 is taken as the starting point of the second line. At the same time we should also look at j==i. Because the end of the second line should be the value of i. If both of these comparisons are true, the value of i should be displayed.
Otherwise 0 should be displayed in the else part.

The inner loop displays the line, so that the line must end at the end of the loop to go down a line. It should be displayed as endl.

For example, let's substitute 5 for this

### **1st Iteration**

**Outer loop**

i=0; i<5; i++

**inner loop**

j=0; j<=i; j++

Here the if condition is true (i==0). Therefore, the first '1' is displayed

### **2nd Iteration**

**Outer loop**

i=1; i<5; i++

**inner loop**

j=0; j<=1; j++

Here the if condition is false (i==0) but else if condition is true(j==0 || j==1). Now '11' displayed as output here

### **3rd Iteration**

**Outer loop**

i=2; i<5; i++

**inner loop**

j=0; j<=2; j++

Here the if condition also false (i==0) but else if condition is true the first time(j==0). The second time it will be false. So it goes to the else part. Again the third time else if part is true.
Now '202' displayed as output here.

After running this way until the outer loop i<=5, the final output can be seen as follows

1

11

202

3003

40004

Answer (score 0):

any line is of the following form ...

i is the line index ... then starting form 0

```
for i = 0 return 1;
else
//number is then 
// 1 <= i <= max
int n = i * pow( 10, i ) + i;
```